# Take a formatted list in file to list python

Tags: python, list, file

I have a file with a list of letters corresponding to another letter:

```
A['B', 'D']
B['A', 'E']
C[]
D['A', 'G']
E['B', 'H']
F[]
G['D']
H['E']
```

I need to import these lists to their corresponding letter, to hopefully have variables that look like this:

```
vertexA = ['B', 'D']
vertexB = ['A', 'E']
vertexC = []
vertexD = ['A', 'G']
vertexE = ['B', 'H']
vertexF = []
vertexG = ['D']
vertexH = ['E']
```

What would be the best way to do this? I tried searching for an answer but was unlucky in doing so. Thanks for any help.

Comment: is it `txt` file or what?

Comment: Yes, I have this information in a file called out.txt

Comment: No, variables are the wrong approach here. You need to use a data structure, such as a `list` or `dict`.

Comment: Can you please show what you've tried? Can you provide a [mcve] or your problem?

Comment: A dictionary might be a good container for your data.  You need to open the file then; for each line, extract the key and the values, add the values to the key in the dictionary.

Comment: [This grid](http://imgur.com/a/I2Htl) (sorry for bad mouse writing) is part of a puzzle, where you must find the probability that you can go to A from H, where the lines, each time you start, have a 50% chance of breaking. You can only go when a bridge is intact. I have already written code that determines each vertex's possible neighbors. The list is written to a file, and then I need to find if it is possible to get to H from A, using the neighbors.

Comment: I've faced a similar problem before, DON'T use eval or exec, makes everything harder, use a list or dictionary

Comment: The correct answer is to choose an existing serialization format, like JSON, instead of rolling your own and then having to figure out how to parse it later.

Answer (score 1):

Building a dictionary would probably be best. Each letter of the alphabet would be a key, and then the value would be a list of associated letters. Here's a proof of concept (not tested):

```
from string import string.ascii_uppercase

vertices = {}

# instantiate dict with uppercase letters of alphabet
for c in ascii_uppercase:
    vertices[c] = []

# iterate over file and populate dict
with open("out.txt", "rb") as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if line[0].upper() not in ascii_uppercase:
            # you probably want to do some additional error checking
            print("Error on line {}: {}".format(i, line))
        else:  # valid uppercase letter at beginning of line
            list_open = line.index('[')
            list_close = line.rindex(']') + 1  # one past end
            # probably would want to validate record is in correct format before getting here
            # translate hack to remove unwanted chars
            row_values = line[list_open:list_close].translate(None, "[] '").split(',')
            # do some validation for cases where row_values is empty
            vertices[line[0].upper()].extend([e for e in row_values if e.strip() != ''])
```

Using it would then be easy:

```
for v in vertices['B']:
    # do something with v
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try using dictionaries rather than variables, and I think it makes it easier as well to populate your data from your textfile.

```
vertex = {}
vertex['A'] = ['B', 'D']
vertex['A']
>>> ['B', 'D']
```

Answer (score 1):

When you read your input file, the inputs should look like this:

```
string='A["B","C"]'
```

So, we know that the first letter is the name of the list.

```
import ast
your_list=ast.literal_eval(string[1:])

your_list:
['B', 'C']
```

You can take care of the looping, reading file, and string manipulation for proper naming...

Answer (score 0):

File A.txt:

```
A['B', 'D']
B['A', 'E']
C[]
D['A', 'G']
E['B', 'H']
F[]
G['D']
H['E']
```

The code:

```
with open('A.txt','r') as file:
   file=file.read().splitlines()
   listy=[[elem[0],elem[1:].strip('[').strip(']').replace("'",'').replace(' ','').split(',')] for elem in file]
```

This makes a nested list, but as Christian Dean said, is a better way to go.

Result:

```
[['A', ['B', 'D']], ['B', ['A', 'E']], ['C', ['']], ['D', ['A', 'G']], ['E', ['B', 'H']], ['F', ['']], ['G', ['D']], ['H', ['E']]]
```